# URL encoding in Android

Tags: android, url, urlencode

How do you encode a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) in Android?

I thought it was like this:

```
final String encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(urlAsString, "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL(encodedURL);
```

If I do the above, the `http://` in `urlAsString` is replaced by `http%3A%2F%2F` in `encodedURL` and then I get a  `java.net.MalformedURLException` when I use the URL.

Answer (score 700, accepted):

You don't encode the entire URL, only parts of it that come from "unreliable sources".

- Java:

  ```
  String query = URLEncoder.encode("apples oranges", Charsets.UTF_8.name());
  String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
  ```
- Kotlin:

  ```
  val query: String = URLEncoder.encode("apples oranges", Charsets.UTF_8.name())
  val url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=$query"
  ```

Alternatively, you can use [Strings.urlEncode(String str)](https://github.com/yanchenko/droidparts/blob/master/droidparts/src/org/droidparts/util/Strings.java) of [DroidParts](https://github.com/droidparts/droidparts) that doesn't throw checked exceptions.

Or use something like

```
String uri = Uri.parse("http://...")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
                .build().toString();
```

Comment: What if the whole url is unreliable? Should I encode everything except the protocol? I kind of expected a convenience method to do this.

Comment: Then it's just a broken url. The idea is to prevent the query part from breaking the url.

Comment: @hgpc - take a look at section 3 of RFC3986 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3).  It tells you how to encode the various portions of a URI.  Unfortunately each portion of the URI (host, path, query, etc.) has slightly different encoding rules.

Comment: This is fine in you are just dealing with a specific part of a URL and you know how to construct or reconstruct the URL.  For a more general approach which can handle any url string, see my answer below.

Comment: @yanchenko What if the last path of my url is `apples ははは.pdf` so the space should be dealt with first, then encode it. So it's now `apples%20ははは.pdf` but then if you encode it after, it becomes `apples%2520%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AF.pdf` instead of `apples%20%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AF.pdf`. How do you handle spacing and encoding?

Comment: Why am I getting a deprecation warning using this? Used `Uri.encode(query);` instead.

Comment: @yanchenko I want to share link in social media (telegrm, viber,...) that contain utf-8, tried your way buy not good, what to do with this: http://yazd20.com//News/2015/11/استند-آب-كمدي-حسن-ريوندي-در-يزد.html

Comment: Attention, the URL documentation states: "The URLEncoder and URLDecoder classes can also be used, but only for HTML form encoding, which is not the same as the encoding scheme defined in RFC2396." Therefore if you use this URL for example for HTTP calls, I believe the URI class should rather be used for encoding.

Comment: How do I set a custom caption? For example I read "Google" and it contains the url "https://www.google.it/"

Comment: `Uri.Builder` is *[Not safe for concurrent use.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder)*

Answer (score 174):

I'm going to add one suggestion here.  You can do this which avoids having to get any external libraries.

Give this a try:

```
String urlStr = "http://abc.dev.domain.com/0007AC/ads/800x480 15sec h.264.mp4";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```

You can see that in this particular URL, I need to have those spaces encoded so that I can use it for a request.

This takes advantage of a couple features available to you in Android classes.  First, the URL class can break a url into its proper components so there is no need for you to do any string search/replace work.  Secondly, this approach takes advantage of the URI class feature of properly escaping components when you construct a URI via components rather than from a single string.

The beauty of this approach is that you can take any valid url string and have it work without needing any special knowledge of it yourself.

Comment: It can also be a good idea to urldecode urlStr before sending it to the URL constructor. URLDecoder.decode(urlStr)

Comment: One could also use the `android.net.Uri` and `android.net.Uri.Builder` classes in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the post :) But I am facing a problem. If the url is already encoded partially, it is encoding the already encoded parts. What should I do? For example: http://dj-videos.us/Music/XclusiveSinGleTrack/320%20Kbps/November%202013/Yo%20Yo%20Honey%20Singh%20-%20Blue%20Eyes-[DJKANG.Com].mp3 The %20 is coded to %2520

Comment: @berserk If it is already encoded, don't encode it. You shouldn't get into a state where it is partially encoded, or you aren't sure whether it is or isn't encoded.

Comment: @EJP Actually I am getting this url from some source. Its in partial encoded state.

Comment: This method doesn't encode characters like ğ to %C4%9F. Accepted one encodes!

Answer (score 86):

For android, I would use 
String android.net.Uri.encode(String s)

> Encodes characters in the given string as '%'-escaped octets using the UTF-8 scheme. Leaves letters ("A-Z", "a-z"), numbers ("0-9"), and unreserved characters ("_-!.~'()*") intact. Encodes all other characters.

Ex/

```
String urlEncoded = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + Uri.encode(query);
```

Comment: Unfortunately `Uri.encode("a=1&b=1")` produces `a%3D1%26b%3D1` but expected `a=1&b=1`

Comment: @loentar That's the expected result. If the user enters `a=1&b=1` as a query, you want to query exactly that.

Comment: How different this with URLEncoder.encode(StringHere,"UTF-8")

Comment: @stuckedoverflow For one thing, Uri.encode(str) does not throw a checked exception unlike  URLEncoder.encode(str,"UTF-8")

Answer (score 52):

Also you can use this

```
private static final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
String urlEncoded = Uri.encode(path, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
```

it's the most simple method

Comment: this is not the best solution, but it is definitely a nice quick fix...thanx

Comment: This is the quickest fix when the whole URL is unreliable. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the % should be allowed? Should it not be encoded?

Comment: How to encode this url to be possible to share and then user be able to open the link and see the page :   http://yazd20.com//News/2015/11/استند-آب-كمدي-حسن-ريوندي-در-يزد.html

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
                    query = URLEncoder.encode(query, "utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use below methods

```
public static String parseUrl(String surl) throws Exception
{
    URL u = new URL(surl);
    return new URI(u.getProtocol(), u.getAuthority(), u.getPath(), u.getQuery(), u.getRef()).toString();
}
```

or

```
public String parseURL(String url, Map<String, String> params)
{
    Builder builder = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon();
    for (String key : params.keySet())
    {
        builder.appendQueryParameter(key, params.get(key));
    }
    return builder.build().toString();
}
```

the second one is better than first.

Answer (score 0):

Find Arabic chars and replace them with its UTF-8 encoding.
some thing like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < urlAsString.length(); i++) {
    if (urlAsString.charAt(i) > 255) {
        urlAsString = urlAsString.substring(0, i) + 
          URLEncoder.encode(urlAsString.charAt(i)+"", "UTF-8") + 
          urlAsString.substring(i+1);
    }
}
encodedURL = urlAsString;
```