# how to url encode in android?

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

I am using grid view for displaying image using xml parsing,i got some exception like

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at
>   index 80:
>   http://www.theblacksheeponline.com/party_img/thumbspps/912big_361999096_Flicking
>   Off Douchebag.jpg

How to solve this problem? I want to display all kind of url,anybody knows please give sample code for me.

Thanks All

Comment: An URL with a white space instead of %20 is an illegal URL. So you need a parser for broken urls (unless you can change them manually before parsing).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Url encoding in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)

Answer (score 29):

URL encoding is done in the same way on android as in Java SE;

```
try {
    String url = "http://www.example.com/?id=123&art=abc";
    String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
    Log.d("TEST", encodedurl);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @http://www.theblacksheeponline.com/party_img/thumbspps/12390867930_15951_186997180114_709920114_4296270_6115611_n[1].jpg
How can i encode this kind of url?please give sample code for me..

Comment: That example outputs the URL: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%3Fid%3D123%26art%3Dabc . That's not a valid URL at all.  The URLEncoder.encode method is for encoding query string values rather than whole URLs. Quote from docs: 'This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format'

Comment: That's not a valid encoding. Look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

Comment: It would be nice to fix your example... or delete it.

Comment: How to encode this url to be possible to share and then user be able to open the link and see the page :   http://yazd20.com//News/2015/11/استند-آب-كمدي-حسن-ريوندي-در-يزد.html

Comment: thanx alot.. it worked, but it shows `20%` instead of spaces, so I had to replace it with normal spaces like this > `URLEncoder.encode(note,"UTF-8").trim().replace(" ", "%20")`

Answer (score 16):

Also you can use this

```
private static final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
String urlEncoded = Uri.encode(path, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
```

it's the most simple method

Comment: Great workaround. How did you arrive at the `ALLOWED_URI_CHARS` list?

Comment: There's also an overload that doesn't take `ALLOWED_URI_CHARS`

Answer (score 6):

As Ben says in his comment, you should not use URLEncoder.encode to full URLs because you will change the semantics of the URL per the following example from the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html):

> The URIs
>   http://www.w3.org/albert/bertram/marie-claude
>   and
>   http://www.w3.org/albert/bertram%2Fmarie-claude
>   are NOT identical, as in the second
>   case the encoded slash does not have
>   hierarchical significance.

Instead, you should encode component parts of a URL independently per the following from   [RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html) Section 2.4

> Under normal circumstances, the only
>   time when octets within a URI are
>   percent-encoded is during the process
>   of producing the URI from its
>   component parts.  This is when an
>   implementation determines which of the
>   reserved characters are to be used as
>   subcomponent delimiters and which can
>   be safely used as data.  Once
>   produced, a URI is always in its
>   percent-encoded form.

So, in short, for your case you should encode/escape your filename and then assemble the URL.

Answer (score 4):

You don't encode the *entire URL*, only *parts of it* that come from "unreliable sources" like.

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("Hare Krishna ", "utf-8");
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
```

Answer (score 1):

URLEncoder should be used only to encode queries, use [java.net.URI](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class instead:

```
URI uri = new URI(
    "http",
    "www.theblacksheeponline.com", 
    "/party_img/thumbspps/912big_361999096_Flicking Off Douchebag.jpg",
    null);
String request = uri.toASCIIString();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below method

```
public String parseURL(String url, Map<String, String> params)
{
    Builder builder = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon();
    for (String key : params.keySet())
    {
        builder.appendQueryParameter(key, params.get(key));
    }
    return builder.build().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with URLEncoder that added (+) sign in replace of (" "), but it was not working and getting 404 url not found error.

Then i googled for get better answer and found this and its working awesome.

```
String urlStr = "http://www.example.com/test/file name.mp4";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```

This way of encoding url its very useful because using of URL we can separate url into different part. So, there is no need to perform any string operation.

Then second URI class, this approach takes advantage of the URI class feature of properly escaping components when you construct a URI via components rather than from a single string.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a quick URI encoder for this purpose.  It even handles unicode characters.
http://www.dmurph.com/2011/01/java-uri-encoder/

Comment: What a sweet waste of time. ;) Android does have a Uri class as well.