# IllegalArgumentException when I try execute request

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception

In my code I catch IllegalArgumentException (Illegal character in query at index 85) in line where I execute request to server. Work with was build as patter Command, another tasks completes correct but not this:

```
public CreateCommentTask(String barcodeId, String ball, String comment,
        String sign) {
    super(getApplicationUrl() + "?command=createComment" + "&barcodeId="
            + barcodeId + "&ball=" + ball + "&text=" + comment
            + "&sessionId=" + sign);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

So, I have only adres and some data in string formate. My app crash in this line:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(task.createRequest());
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What are the strings you're passing to this method? The barcodeId, ball, comment, and sign

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734844/how-to-url-encode-in-android) about url encoding in android.

Comment: @Geobits, I pass this strings:
 String barcodeId = "4605246006340";
 String ball = "10"; 
 String comment = java.net.URLEncoder.encode("Mycomment", "UTF-8");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you need to URL encode the parameters (most probably the `comment` variable).

EDIT: you can use java.net.URI to generate the proper query. Try this:

```
super(new URI(getApplicationUrl() + "?command=createComment" + "&barcodeId="
            + barcodeId + "&ball=" + ball + "&text=" + comment
            + "&sessionId=" + sign).toString());
```

Comment: this aproach didn't help me. Yes, I must use URLEncoder for comment and I do it - java.net.URLEncoder.encode("My comment", "UTF-8"), but it is not work.

Comment: The space between "my" and "comment" replaced on "+" but should be on "%20"

Comment: You don't want to use URLEncoder, in effect you want to use URI component encoding rules. Take a look at the class shown at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607176/java-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent-that-produces-identical-output

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build the string beforehand and log it? Then you could see what character 85 is. I guarantee the problem is there if that's what the log says. If you can't figure out why, post the resulting string up, along with the rest of the log.

```
public CreateCommentTask(String barcodeId, String ball, String comment,
        String sign) {
    String query = getApplicationUrl() + "?command=createComment" + "&barcodeId="
            + barcodeId + "&ball=" + ball + "&text=" + comment
            + "&sessionId=" + sign;
    Log.d("HOLYCRAP", query);
    super(query);
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry: I already solved issue with this exception but I have catched another ClientProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response. I forget check my question as solved.

Comment: You should probably update your question so there's no more confusion. And you're going to want to put way more information that that, trust me