# Removing White spaces from a string for http connection

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send a query url

```
String url = String.format(
   "http://xxxxx/xxx/xxx&message=%s",myEditBox.getText.toString());
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httpclient.getCookieStore().addCookie(cooki);
try {
   ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
   httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.connection-manager.timeout", 15000);
   String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

gives me error, `illegal character at query`. That's `white space` probably. How to deal with this issue?

Best Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

Comment: You can use URLEncoder for that 
Try these

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734844/how-to-url-encode-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode your url.

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode(myEditBox.getText.toString(), "utf-8");
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
 httpclient.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset","UTF-8");
 url="http://xxxxx/xxx/xxx&message="+URLEncoder.encode(myEditBox.getText.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Oh... I posted just 25 seconds late :D

Answer (score 0):

Try .trim() while get value from edittext.
May be whitespace come from edittext and also use "utf-8".

see below code.

```
String value = URLEncoder.encode(myEditBox.getText.toString().trim(), "utf-8");
String url = "http://xxxxx/xxx/xxx&message=%s" + value;
```