# how to form a url for google maps that contains &

Tags: android, google-maps

In my android application, upon clicking a link I have to open up google maps page. In google maps I am prepopulating the source and destination address. Source address is my current location and destination address is a predefined one. My destination address contains '&'. So while loading the google maps, the destination address comes only till this '&'.

Suppose the address is: ABC & Co.

In google maps it comes only till ABC as destination address. The rest '& Co.' is not shown.

Why is it so?

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried formatting it with

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("ABC & Co.");
```

before using it in your URL? This essentially does what you are doing in your answer but it will work on any string.

[URL encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)

Comment: what is the rawStr? When I entered my address over there its showing error...its saying it should be List<? extends NameValuePair>

Comment: My bad, I did give you the wrong method. That was for encoding parameter pairs. I've updated my answer with the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it worked. Give the URL escape character for '&'. Its value is `%26`