# Create a URL Friendly string Android

Tags: java, android

I want to write a function that takes a string and cleans it form url un-friendly characters, using a regular expression or something else, how can this be achieved?
Thanks

Comment: What's an "unfriendly" character? You mean as a URL?

Comment: for example a space, #, ? .... thanks

Comment: Perhaps you meant "encode"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

Comment: You can use URLEncoder.encode, or something like: private static String encodeForUrl(String input) { return input.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z\\s]", "").replaceAll("\\s", "-"); } to manually replace all non-URL-friendly characters

Comment: Android is an operating system. You are not writing a function in an operating system. You are writing a method in Java.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android