# Json in http parameter

Tags: android, json

I want to send json object in the http url link as below

```
http://domainname/xyz?abc=[{"State":"Ap","LastName":"S","FirstName":"James","Email":"adc@gmail.com","Country":"India","City":"Hyd","Barcode":"6598","RecordId":"1234"},{"State":"MP","LastName":"K","FirstName":"Singham","Email":"abc@gmail.com","Country":"India","City":"GN","Barcode":"123","RecordId":"123456","FollowupTypes":"Send Sample;Followup Types"}]
```

any one help to send a request like this

Thanking you

Comment: use [URLEncoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android) for parameter `abc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Google's gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to encode your object (or array) in json and then add it to the URL :

```
String url = "http://domainname/xyz?abc=" + URLEncoder.encode(gson.toJson(yourObj), "UTF-8");
```

You may also use the new [Android Json Writer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonWriter.html).

Comment: +1 Google gson is really intuitive and works well on Android!