# Android JSON parsing , can't connect to service

Tags: android, json, url, youtube, connection

i m trying to write a method for calling service and get JSON data back in Android application. assume all necessary gloable variables are declared already...

these are the lib i m using:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

here is my code:

```
public class JSONParser {

String url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/eon/uploads?&v=2&max-   results=50&alt=jsonc"; 

JSONObject jObj = null;
JSONArray ja = null;
String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

 }



  public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url){
    try {
          URL urlGetter = new URL(url);
        URLConnection tc = urlGetter.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"), 8);

          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }


         json = sb.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      //parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return jObj;
   }
```

it just dose not work, i tried to run in debug mode, when it run to this line:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            tc.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

it complains about : java.net.UnknownHostException: gdata.youtube.com
i don't know how to solve this problem... any suggestions?
thanks

by the way, in my android manifest, i have permit internet already:

if you look up the url  in browser, you can see the json format of ti ...and it can be connected...but my code just complaining about unknowhostexception...."http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/eon/uploads?&v=2&max-   results=50&alt=jsonc";

Comment: Are you connected to the Internet by either mobile/wifi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please put the permissions in your androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to encode the url using [urlEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html)..as the url contains space that needs to be replaced with %20..check https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286128/1434631