# HttpPost escaped parameter

Tags: java, post, httpclient

I am trying to make a HttpPost using the HttpClient(HttpComponents). This is my code:

```
try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
            post.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
            post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", new String(code.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "googleClientId"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8080/myapp/test"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "ClientSecret"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));


            HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);

            if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                   + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                             new InputStreamReader((resp.getEntity().getContent())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
                res = res + output;
            }
            System.out.println(output);
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(res);
```

I get a `400` code. I suspect it is because all the parameters I set contain special characters, like `_ . and /` and they are getting escaped. How can I avoid this? Or am I missing the real problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

Comment: @Nambari This is Post, so I have nothing to do with the url.

Comment: @Nambari What am I missing? Am I sending my parameters in the URL somehow?

Comment: It seems you are. Could you just add one by one and narrow down which param could be causing the issue/.

Comment: @Nambari Apparently I was wrong. It's `redirect_uri`. Do you have any experience with OAuth2?

Comment: @Nambari I have finally solved it! This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldnt http header "Content-Type" be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` since you are explicitly URL encoding the post parameters?

Comment: Am I encoding the parameters in the URL??? Aren't they transmitted in the Post body?

Comment: If it is so, how can I transmit the parameters in the request body?

Comment: I finally solved it. This was only part of the problem, the rest was solved with according to the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch Thank you!

Comment: Youre welcome. Please vote for my answer if you think it helped you in any way. Thank you.

Comment: I will also accept the answer, since it solved part of the problem

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully it will help somebody else in future with a similar problem.