# Bad URL encoding for images

Tags: java, android, url-encoding

In my app, there is an ImageView that display an image from a URL.

I download the image using this method:

```
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
```

This works only with URLs that has numbers or english letters and doesn't work with any other chars (like spaces):

**Good URL:** http://site.com/images/image.png

**Bad URL:** http://site.com/images/image 1.png

I tried to chage the URL encoding (URLEncoder.encode), but it changes the whole URL (incliding slashes, ect...).

Do I need to replace some chars after the encoding? or maybe there is a better way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[Url encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)"

> You don't encode the entire URL, only parts of it that come from
>   "unreliable sources". -yanchenko

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("apples oranges", "utf-8");
String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
```

> This is fine if you are just dealing with a specific part of a URL and
>   you know how to construct or reconstruct the URL. For a more general
>   approach which can handle any url string, see my answer below. – Craig
>   B

```
String urlStr = "http://abc.dev.domain.com/0007AC/ads/800x480 15sec h.264.mp4";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```

Comment: Thanks! :) but there is still a little problem: it doesn't work with hebrew chars. What should I do?

Comment: I think you need to encode the Hebrew character part explicitly using  URLEncoder. Seems only few non-ASCII characters are taken care by URI, check "Encoding and Decoding URI Components" section in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and also check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2744184/909271)

Comment: are you using a URL or a IRI (Internationalized Resource Identifier)?

Comment: There are hebrew chars in it (http://site.com/images/עברית.png), so it's IRI, isn't it? I'm a bit confused right now...

Comment: Its an IRI, so you need to follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls/2744184#2744184). Also its mentioned in [android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html): A URI's host, port and scheme are not eligible for encoding and must not contain illegal characters. So take the part which is hebrew and encode it before constructing an URI.

Comment: How should I encode the hebrew part? URLEncoder.encode(hebrewPart, "utf-8") doesn't work.

Comment: try this ... `URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), URLEncoder.encode(url.getPath(), "utf-8"), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());`   and also check out [android IDN](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/IDN.html) for domain names.