# Encode Image URL from spaces

Tags: android, url, encoding, bitmap, special-characters

I'm developing a RSS reader app, but I'm facing problems with the image URLs becuase they contain spaces. I tried several techniques from these forums but they all give me different errors. I tried replacing the space with %20 but I'm getting file not found exception.
This is the method in which I'm fetching the image:

```
//String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
            //url = Uri.encode(url, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
            //URL urlnew = new URL(url);
            //URI uri = new URI(urlnew.getProtocol(), urlnew.getUserInfo(), urlnew.getHost(), urlnew.getPort(), urlnew.getPath(), urlnew.getQuery(), urlnew.getRef());
            //urlnew = uri.toURL();
            //url = URLEncoder.encode(url.replace(" ", "%20"), "utf-8");
            url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            Log.i("Code:",conn.getResponseCode()+" "+conn.getResponseMessage());
            Log.i("Error Message",conn.getErrorStream()+"");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
```

The commented commands at the top are some commands I got from other people.
LogCat:

```
02-20 13:58:19.015: W/System.err(29109): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ghadinews.net/upload/new/GhadiNews%20-%20parrot%20-%20ly.jpg
02-20 13:58:19.015: W/System.err(29109):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
02-20 13:58:19.015: W/System.err(29109):    at com.betaclass.ghadinews.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:94)
02-20 13:58:19.015: W/System.err(29109):    at com.betaclass.ghadinews.ImageLoader.access$0(ImageLoader.java:63)
02-20 13:58:19.015: W/System.err(29109):    at com.betaclass.ghadinews.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:168)
02-20 13:58:19.020: W/System.err(29109):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
02-20 13:58:19.020: W/System.err(29109):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-20 13:58:19.020: W/System.err(29109):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-20 13:58:19.020: W/System.err(29109):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-20 13:58:19.020: W/System.err(29109):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-20 13:58:19.020: W/System.err(29109):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

If I insert the encoded URL which contains %20 into the browser the image opens normally so the links are working.

Comment: Why don't you use + instead of %20?

Comment: Did you add Internet permission in manifest file ?

Comment: @rciovati : i tried it it gives me the same error (FileNotFoundException)

Comment: @GodOfAndroid : yes of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String urlStr = "http://abc.dev.domain.com/0007AC/ads/800x480 15sec h.264.mp4";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```

Related: [Bad URL encoding for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324075/bad-url-encoding-for-images?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked perfectly, although as you can see from my code above I had tried it before and it didn't work, but I removed conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
and then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Remove both :

```
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

Hope this should solve the problem.

Comment: removed it still same exception :/

Comment: tried it, I still get the same exception. The code works perfectly if the links don't contain spaces. But the problem is that they do.

Comment: Try this : String url = "";
   url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
   try {
    url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8");
   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: I actually merged your answer with the "PsyGik" answer to get it to work, his method doesn't work without removing the commands you told me to remove :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this technique

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("apples oranges", "utf-8");
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
```

Or use something like

```
String uri = Uri.parse("http://...")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
                .build().toString();
```