# Uniersal Image Loader not working with spaces in url

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using image loader to

```
imgL.displayImage(url, imageview, options);
```

It is working with image urls without spaces, but not working with image urls with spaces. For example:

```
http://hitbullseye.com/includes/testmaster_pdffiles/Indian Army.png
```

I am getting following error for this:

```
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914): http://www.hitbullseye.com/includes/testmaster_pdffiles/1404249135Indian Army.png
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.hitbullseye.com/includes/testmaster_pdffiles/1404249135Indian Army.png
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:111)
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:77)
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:319)
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:298)
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:241)
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:141)
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-05 18:07:13.794: E/ImageLoader(5914):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

I also tried

```
url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
```

but same error. Any idea?

Comment: pls check below links
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908410/encode-image-url-from-spaces

Comment: @user3275138 I already tried it.

Comment: UIL works with spaces (they should be encoded). But in your case URL `http://hitbullseye.com/includes/testmaster_pdffiles/Indian%20Army.png` doesn't work but `http://www.hitbullseye.com/includes/testmaster_pdffiles/Indian%20Army.png` works. I can't say why `www` matters.

Comment: @NOSTRA Hmm. Quite strange because I have other urls without spaces that do not have www, and they work fine.