# Opening URL containing a # from an Android Activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to open a URL containing a #, using this:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(url)));
```

But when browser opens, the # is ignored... I don't know why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to construct the URL properly using URL class [URL encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)

```
String urlStr = "http://abc.dev.domain.com/0007AC/ads/800x480 15sec h.264.mp4";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```