# ANDROID: Code not working after inserting Date string to GET Url

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-asynctask, client-server

I am making a android client that reports its location to my server after every 10 seconds.
For server I'm using dynamic DNS. I have to sent latitude, longitude and time-stamp as GET parameters.
I made the following working code:
    package in.kirancity.trackapp;

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

TextView textLat;
TextView textLong;
TextView textRes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
    textRes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textRes);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new myLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, ll);
}

    class myLocationListener implements LocationListener{
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0)
        {
            if(arg0 != null)
            {
                double plong = arg0.getLongitude();
                double plat = arg0.getLatitude();
                String url = "http://vishalhome.myftp.org/insert.php?la="+Double.toString(plat)+"&ln="+Double.toString(plong)+"&d='Arbitrary'";
                textLat.setText(Double.toString(plat));
                textLong.setText(Double.toString(plong));
                new RequestTask().execute(url);
             }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
}
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    responseString = out.toString();
                } else{
                    //Closes the connection.
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textRes);
            tv.setText(result);
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

This code works fine for me. But instead of sending actual time-stamp i sent "Arbitrary" string.
After successfully executing asyncTask, the values are inserted and Response is: "inserted"(Returned by my php page).

But when I'm trying this in onLocationChanged:

```
String url = "http://vishalhome.myftp.org/insert.php?la="+Double.toString(plat)+"&ln="+Double.toString(plong)+"&d=\'";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
url = url + currentDateandTime + "\'";
```

the application crashes on location change event.
I tried to put try catch blocks, but no clue of problem.
I think problem is coming out after new RequestTask(url) is called.
Please assist !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should encode the url before using it. Try this:

```
currentDateandTime = URLEncoder.encode(currentDateandTime, "utf-8");
url = url + currentDateandTime + "\'";
```

Please see [URL encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution worked for me. Today is the deadline for submitting this complete project. :)
Do you have any idea about how to get high Precision Location in this code? i read somewhere that i need  to put enableHighAccuracy="true" somewhere.

Comment: Welcome. I think you can try <uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission> in the manifest file. Good luck with the project!

Comment: To get accurate location [best location](http://goo.gl/RdYxI). [this](http://goo.gl/p6lS9) link may help u.

Comment: actually my above code returns as 29.88971027, 77.96007911 precision.
while i want it to send like 29.891796984361115,77.95791149139404
need help