# getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while uploading to server in android

Tags: android, json

```
04-30 18:33:23.036: E/AndroidRuntime(22231): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 54: http://www.slicapp.com/slic/edit_profile.php?message=[{&email1=prabhjotkaur3@hotmail.com&email2=bgf&email3=hg&facebook=ggf&twitter=&gplus=&youtube=&linkedin=&instagram=&tumblr=ggf&udid1251935507&fbuid1251935507&fbid& fbpw}]
04-30 18:33:23.036: E/AndroidRuntime(22231):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:970)
04-30 18:33:23.036: E/AndroidRuntime(22231):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
```

Comment: And what's the code you're using?

Comment: Just check if your `URL` is valid one ! I see a space between `&` and `fbpw` !

Answer (score 2):

You have a space in your query between the amp `&` abd `fbpw`..

```
http://www.slicapp.com/slic/edit_profile.php?message=[{&email1=prabhjotkaur3@hotmail.com&email2=bgf&email3=hg&facebook=ggf&twitter=&gplus=&youtube=&linkedin=&instagram=&tumblr=ggf&udid1251935507&fbuid1251935507&fbid& fbpw}]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ^
```

Also, note as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547922/264775) answer, the brackets `[` and `]` may need to be percent escaped (the first one you have is the index complained about). Quoted:

> The '[' and ']' characters are  characters and should be
>   percent escaped if not used as delimiters in the scheme-specific
>   syntax. The spec says:
>
> > "URI producing applications should percent-encode data octets that
> >     correspond to characters in the reserved set unless these characters
> >     are specifically allowed by the URI scheme to represent data in that
> >     component."

Comment: I am not getting from this link how to decode [,{ if i removing these bracket no error is coming so please suggest me how to encode [,{,}]

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

Comment: By checking this webservice can u please tell me is this is HttpGet or Post  i am using HTTP Post method can u please check this?