# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException for url embedded with special character

Tags: java, android, regex, string, url

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Illegal character in query at index 49: `http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=?^NDX,^BANK&f=nsl1opc1`

im getting the malformed url exception on the 'caret' (^) symbol..came to know that the caret is used heavily in regex and in other cases this character is particularly removed from a desired string.

Is this not possible to have strings/urls with `'caret' (^)` symbol

In the above case to retrieve index data i need to have that symbol..

Comment: Maybe you should [encode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) the character. The code for caret is `%5E`.

Comment: try encoding the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

Comment: %5E is printing as it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed not legal to have a caret in a query string part.

Use the constructor for `URI` instead:

```
final URL url = new URI("http", "download.finance.yahoo.com", "/d/quotes.csv",
    "s=?^NDX,^BANK&f=nsl1opc1", null).toURL();
```

This will take care of all the necessary encoding issues for you.

See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Well, there is no reason why it should not work. Try it and see ;)

Comment: Side note: if you have many URLs to build that way, one project of mine may be useful: https://github.com/fge/uri-template