# Force Close asynctask (Illegal Character)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am getting this error, which is odd because it works from another activity calling the same async task. I can not figure out what the illegal character is in my query:

```
09-06 17:42:29.098  32101-32497/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 50: http://beerportfolio.com/app_getTopTaste.php?t=Rum
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
        at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetTopTasteBeersJSON.readJSONFeed(GetTopTasteBeersJSON.java:139)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetTopTasteBeersJSON.doInBackground(GetTopTasteBeersJSON.java:49)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetTopTasteBeersJSON.doInBackground(GetTopTasteBeersJSON.java:34)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Try encoding your url


     `String url = URLEncoder.encode("your url", "utf-8")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to trim the string. It removes unwanted whitespace at the end of the string.

```
String url = " http://beerportfolio.com/app_getTopTaste.php?t=Rum";
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

> Illegal character in query at index 50: http://beerportfolio.com/app_getTopTaste.php?t=Rum

It's the character at index 50, which is right after "Rum". It's probably some sort of whitespace character. You'll have to post your code for how you get/generate that URL if you want more details, but you might need to add some code to strip whitespace somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    String url = " http://beerportfolio.com/app_getTopTaste.php?t=Rum";
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); 
    Log.i(".......",_response);
```

I just tried your url and i do get the response

```
09-06 22:05:04.547: I/.......(1460): [{"beer":"Rum Cask","rate":"5","id":"dkRDyR","breweryID":"jC0TAa"}]
```

As kabuko stated character 50 is after Rum. I think kabuko is right.

I guess you have space at the end of url. It is better to encode the url as below.

```
    String query = URLEncoder.encode("Rum  ", "utf-8");
    String url = "http://beerportfolio.com/app_getTopTaste.php?t=" + query;
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
```

[URL encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)