# Equals sign in url not working

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

i got a problem which i tried hard to solve with searching with google because will be a simple solution.

I want to open the following url:

```
http://<<IP>>/query.html?sql="select * from ADAnreden"
```

To do this, i write this url in a string to open it with HttpGet...

```
String url = "http://"+ip+"/query.html?sql=\"select * from ADAnreden\"";
```

So i escaped the `"` infront of select and after ADAnreden. But the problem is that the following error is comming up:

```
Illegal character in query at index 36.
```

This is the equals sign. So how can i escape the = ? The backslash is not working.

Thanks for help

Comment: I think wrapping this part in a url encoder should help `\"select * from ADAnreden\"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the escaping for the URL, not for Java. Spaces are not valid in URLs. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android) for more about URL encoding in Android.

Answer (score 2):

you must encode the query before using it as URL, see `URLEncoder.encode(query);`

Comment: this should be comment please!