# UTF-8 String encoding for web url

Tags: java, android, url, encoding, utf-8

In order to make a good String formated url from a previous String I want to know how to encode a String in an other but encoded in UTF-8 ?

My method to encode is here :

```
public static String getUrlScheme(Context ctx, String title,
            String description, double latitude, double longitude) {

        try {

            String titleUtf8 = URLEncoder.encode(title, "utf-8");
            String descriptionUtf8 = URLEncoder.encode(description, "utf-8");

            String urlScheme = ctx.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.url_scheme_base)
                    + "?title="
                    + titleUtf8
                    + "&descr="
                    + descriptionUtf8
                    + "&lat=" + latitude + "&long=" + longitude;

            return urlScheme;

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For example I got :

title : "T çé ü" desc : "" ==>

```
http://..?title=T+%C3%A7%C3%A9+%C3%BC&descr=&lat=...&long=..
```

And the correct url should be (from iOS method) ==> `http://..?title=T%20%C3%A7%C3%A9%20%C3%BC&descr=%20&lat=...&long=...`

title : "HB s6/&" desc : "" ==> `http://..?title=HB+s6&descr=&lat=..long=..`

And the correct url should be (from iOS method) ==>  `http://..?title=HB%20s6&descr=%20&lat=...&long=...`

The problem is that in iOS, using this method : stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding my friend can have a good String encoded in UTF-8.

Please help

**EDIT**

Solved by replacing "+" by "%20" :

```
String titleUtf8 = URLEncoder.encode(title, "utf-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
String descriptionUtf8 = URLEncoder.encode(description, "utf-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
```

Comment: iOS uses %20 escape for an empty space character and Android URLEncode uses + espcape. Both are valid url escaping for an empty character. Use encodedStr.replaceAll("+", "%20") to make them identical.

Comment: Thanks, I solved just replacing all "+" by "%20"

Comment: encodedStr.replaceAll("\\+", "%20") is better. "+" should be escaped.

Answer (score -1):

In Android you also have very fine tools : [URL encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("apples oranges", "utf-8");
String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
```

Comment: Are you joking ?!Keep a view to my method before posting!