# How to get JSON string from curl URL with liferay service builder's web service

Tags: java, json, web-services, curl, liferay

I have created service using service builder and put the sample entity in liferay service.xml file.

**My service.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_2_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="com.temp">
  <namespace></namespace>

  <entity name="Student" local-service="true" remote-service="true">
  </entity>

  <entity name="Foo" uuid="true" local-service="true" remote-service="true">
    <!-- PK fields -->
    <column name="fooId" type="long" primary="true" />

    <!-- Group instance -->
    <column name="groupId" type="long" />

    <!-- Audit fields -->
    <column name="companyId" type="long" />
    <column name="userId" type="long" />
    <column name="userName" type="String" />
    <column name="createDate" type="Date" />
    <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date" />

    <!-- Other fields -->
    <column name="field1" type="String" />
    <column name="field2" type="boolean" />
    <column name="field3" type="int" />
    <column name="field4" type="Date" />
    <column name="field5" type="String" />

    <!-- Order -->
    <order by="asc">
      <order-column name="field1" />
    </order>

    <!-- Finder methods -->
    <finder name="Field2" return-type="Collection">
      <finder-column name="field2" />
    </finder>

    <!-- References -->
    <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.asset" entity="AssetEntry" />
    <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.asset" entity="AssetTag" />
  </entity>
</service-builder>
```

after building the service I have added one method in `FooServiceImpl.java` as below,

```
@JSON
public JSONObject verifyService (String action){
  System.out.println("action----->"+action);
  JSONObject actionData=JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

  actionData.put("success", true);
  return actionData;
}
```

I build the service and able to access it via `localhost:8080/api/jsonws` with admin credential.

Now when I call this service with below curl command

> curl http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/XXXX-Portlets.foo/verify-service
>     -u test@liferay.com:test
>     -d action='temp'

I am able to get the action parameter value in my implemented method.
Now I would like to get below value posted from curl,

> curl http://localhost:8080api/jsonws/XXXXX-Portlets.foo/verify-service
>     -u test@liferay.com:test
>     -d '{"action":"verify"}'

I am not able to get this json in my web service!!

I have tried adding the following

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json
>     -XPOST ...."

to curl and change the parameter type from string to jsonObject but no luck.

Is there any annotation I'm missing here?

Comment: What do you want is to pass JSON object as parameter to remote service, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296578/passing-json-object-in-url-of-restful-web-service-in-android

Comment: parkash I am able to get it by below URL ,       curl http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/XXXX-Portlets.foo/verify-service \   -u test@liferay.com:test \   -d action='{"action":"verify"}'.      But if I am hitting like second CURL command shown in description then i am not able to get the this '{"action":"verify"}'.

Comment: URL parameter is key-value pair. Therefore, you need to pass it like action='{"action":"verify"}', where left hand side action is name of the param.

Comment: Well, if you are passing single value for action, then why are you bothered to pass JSON object. just pass it like action=verify

Comment: That is the issue I want to handle the json paramter like second approach only (-d '{"action":"verify"}') that is why I have asked this question.I don't want to pass like action = 'paramter value'...

Comment: ultimately I want the second approach of curl to be handle with my webservice ...how can I do that...