# Unable to get data from server if url having hyphen,in android

Tags: java, android, json, url

I am sending request to server by using this following url format
`http://api.xyz.com/JSonService.asmx/Category_Name=food-and-drink`.

But my problem is i am not able to send the request as hyphen present in **food-and-drink**,but in my system browser it is working fine..

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: try replacing the hyphen with %2D in the url

Comment: Encode the URL as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

Comment: As @fasteque explained, you need to encode your url. This works in your browser, because it encodes it automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

```
String queryStr = URLEncoder.encode("food-and-drink", "utf-8");
String urlStr = "http://api.xyz.com/JSonService.asmx/Category_Name=" + queryStr;
```

Comment: Please notice that this example in not entirely correct because you don't have to encode the entire URL but just the relevant part like the query string. If you encode the whole URL, also "http://" will be encode as "http%3A%2F%2F" and it will likely cause a java.net.MalformedURLException.