# Error in execution of Try/catch statement in Android

Tags: java, android, try-catch

This code is used to find if a book is available or not.

Now IF the bookname for eg is **Analog Electronics**

and if i Enter input just as **Analog** or **electronics** it will display the full bookname Analog electronics which means that the 1st n 2nd try/catch block were executed properly.

But when i Enter input as **Analog electronics** with a **space** in between the two words it delivers an error and says ***"Check your internet connection*** " even when my internet connection is proper. It catches the error in the 1st try/catch block which should'nt have happened. I am getting an error all because of the "**space**".

```
try {
    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
      "http://duh.com/lol.php?name="+input, 
      postParameters);

    String result = response.toString();

     try{
             returnString = "";
       JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
             for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     Log.i("log_tag","ID: "+json_data.getInt("ID")+
                             ", Bookname: "+json_data.getString("Bookname")+

                     );



                     returnString += "\n" + "Book+ json_data.getString("Bookname");

             }

     }
     catch(JSONException e){
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Book is not availabe" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        toast.getView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }, 3500);
     }

     try{
      tv.setText(returnString);
     }
     catch(Exception e){
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error in Display" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;          
     }   
}
      catch (Exception e) {
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Check your Internet connection" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            toast.getView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }, 3500);               
    };

    }
```

LOG cat error :

```
04-22 20:51:52.589: E/log_tag(1322): Check your internet connection!!java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 52: http://duh.com/lol.php?name=analog electonics
04-22 20:51:52.759: W/EGL_emulation(1322): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Comment: That try/catch block covers everything, so it could be unrelated to your internet connection. Have you looked to see what exception is getting thrown?

Comment: @dcharms the 1st exception gets thrown even when the app is connected to the internet.

Comment: That is my point. It would help if you provided us with the exception being thrown because an uncaught exception anywhere in that block will be caught in that catch.

Comment: @langki05 in the final catch clause, add a line to log the exception thrown, eg: log.e("<your class name>", "exception", e); and then post the logcat output for the exception in your OP

Comment: @panini I have posted the logcat error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your logcat error:

```
04-22 20:51:52.589: E/log_tag(1322): Check your internet connection!!java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 52: http://duh.com/lol.php?name=analog electonics
```

you have an illegal character in your query.

URLs aren't allowed to have a space character in them without it being encoded (see [this page for more details](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)), so you will need to encode your query string before requesting the page.

see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286128/1150776) for the correct way to encode a URL on Android

Comment: Hmmm thanks its making sense now. So now i just have to find out how to encode a space sign.

Comment: if you look at the StackOverflow answer I linked, Android has a built in function that will do URL encoding for you