# Send url from one activity to another

Tags: android, url, android-intent

My main activity has 2 buttons. One to transfer the text to Activity2 and other to transfer url to Activity2.

Code snippet for main activity to send url is as follows:

```
 else if (v.getId()==R.id.SendUrl){
                    String query = mEditText.getText().toString();
                    String url ="www.google.com/#q="+query;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
```

The receiving activity class has the following code:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    // get intent from HomeActivity

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // get extra message
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(HomeActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //render in textview
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewtext);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webNavigator);
    webView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra(HomeActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE));
    //show it in content view

}
```

The intended query does not load. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need too pass the url as string as-

```
String query = mEditText.getText().toString();
                    String url ="http://www.google.com/#q="+query;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,url);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Do not use Uri.parse();
If you want to use the uri you can go by-
following-

```
String uri = Uri.parse("http://...")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
                .build().toString();
```

You can have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android) also.

Add WebView Client to your webview as

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());


And the MyWebViewClient class is an inner class as-

  private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view,url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I removed the Uri.Parse(), however, I still cant get the webactivity to load.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a `Uri` here:

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Uri.parse(url));
```

And try to get a `String` here:

```
webView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra(HomeActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE));
```

The returned `String` will always be `null` because the extra is not a `String`.

If you pass the url like this, you just have to change one line and the code should work:

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, url);
```

Comment: I did remove Uri.parse, however, the web activity still doesn't load.

Comment: Try adding `http://` to the URL in `HomeActivity` additionally to removing `Uri.parse`