# Encoding URL contains Arabic words

Tags: java, android, encoding

I have url for audio file that contains some Arabic words and spaces

```
http://globalmedia.cc/Testing/CMS/main/مسلسلات/مسلسلات كوميدية /يوميات ونيس/الحلقة الثانية.mp3
```

I tried

```
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        url = uri.toURL();
```

the result is // not working

```
http://globalmedia.cc/Testing/CMS/main/مسلسلات/مسلسلات%20كوميدية%20/يوميات%20ونيس/الحلقة%20الثالثة.mp3
```

When i but this link in Google Chrome then copy it again it's become

```
http://globalmedia.cc/Testing/CMS/main/%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA/%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D9%83%D9%88%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%A9%20/%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%B3/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A9.mp3
```

and this worked for me.
I want to do what Google Chrome does by java code?
Hint: URL dose not contains parameters, So i want to encode URL as is.
Any help!

Comment: Finally i found this answer and its working
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21332078/3512164

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String url = "http://globalmedia.cc/Testing/CMS/main/مسلسلات/مسلسلات كوميدية /يوميات ونيس/الحلقة الثانية.mp3";
        try {
            urlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
System.out.println("Encoded URL: "+urlEncoded);
```