# How to escape a string in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, escaping

I can not find an answer to that and I do not know how to compile `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`, which is the only solution I found on the internet.

Also, I do not understand why I can not do something like this

```
s = s.replaceAll(" ","\\ ");
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a string in which I want to escape all characters that need to be escaped in order for the string to be considered a proper query for an url.

Comment: Well adding a backslash certainly doesn't perform URL escaping. It's not like "escaping" is one specification, universally applicable - there are different types of escaping for different contexts. You want URL escaping. I suspect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067 is what you want.

Comment: Then don't use replace all. Use url encode

Comment: Thanks Jon, that is exactly what I looked for. Didn't know there is such a thing as URLEncoder. You can post the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It would be sad if a programming language like Java would not have something like that. :))

Comment: Use java.net.URLEncoder:

java.net.URLEncoder.encode(queryStr, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use

URLEncoder.encode("your URL here", "UTF8")

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String urlStr = "http://abc.dev.domain.com/0007AC/ads/800x480 15sec h.264.mp4";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```

Source: [Url encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962879/1332549)
This should be the correct answer in that post.