# MissingFormatArgumentException with square brackets on android

Tags: android, json, networking, string-formatting, put

I have this string which I'm trying to format:

```
String url = "http://api/doSomething.json?params%5Bemail%5D=%s"
String.format(url,email).
```

The idea is that it ends up looking like this:
http://api/doSomething.json?params[email]=aValue;

I'm currently getting a `MissingFormatArgumentException, Format specifier: 5D` exception.

Has anyone had issues with this before?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yes the strings are in quotes, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i was able to resolve this using a URLEncoder.

This post was particularly helpful -> [URL encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)

```
    String queryPart = String.format(PARAM_STRING,
            email);
    return baseUrl + URLEncoder.encode(queryPart, "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.format()` doesn't like the `%5D` placeholder - `%5D` has to be `%5d`.
Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html
... if it was about placeholders.

Anyway, it seems you just want the square brackets.
Therefore, change this

```
String url = "http://api/doSomething.json?params%5Bemail%5D=%s"
```

to

```
String url = "http://api/doSomething.json?params[email]=%s"
```

Comment: %5d also results in the same exception. I tried using the second suggestion before going with the format. The square brackets cause a problem with the request

Comment: You might want to have a look at this page: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html