# Android URLEncoder.encode unhandled exception java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException

Tags: java, android

I try to implement Android searchable and I want to filter query, I follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android), and others. but in Android Studio I got this message `unhandled exception java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException`, this is my code

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;`
private void doSearch(String queryStr) {
    // get a Cursor, prepare the ListAdapter
    // and set it
    //Log.e("Query",queryStr);
    searchRestaurants(URLEncoder.encode(queryStr, "UTF-8"));}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of doing that?

Comment: When I type ' in search bar My App stoped Working. because in My Server side setting, I disallow ' character and search result is null

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `URLEncoder.encode()`-method in a try-catch block:

```
try {
  URLEncoder.encode(queryStr, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  Log.e("Yourapp", "UnsupportedEncodingException");
}
```

The reason you're getting this error is that some platforms might not support UTF-8 encoding. Android definitely does, so you'll never receive this Exception, but you still need to handle it to make the compiler happy.

However, your code won't do anything, you'll need to store the result of the `encode()`-operation in a variable, e.g. `String myEncodedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(queryStr, "UTF-8");`.

Comment: Wat? I literally handed the code to the OP on a silver platter. I'm happy to provide a link how to perform copy/paste operations on various operating systems, too.

Comment: I do not know about try catch, where i write next code, `URLEncoder.encode(queryStr, "UTF-8");
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RestaurantsRetrofit request = retrofit.create(RestaurantsRetrofit.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call = request.searchRestaurants(queryStr)`

Comment: Please update your question if you're not actually asking about the problem you've formulated in your question.

Comment: This answer not help.

Comment: My answer fixes the problem that you've stated in your question. If you have a different problem, please update your question or post a new question.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
private void doSearch(String queryStr) {
    // get a Cursor, prepare the ListAdapter
    // and set it
    //Log.e("Query",queryStr);
    try {
        final String encodedPath = URLEncoder.encode(queryStr, "UTF-8"));
        searchRestaurants(encodedPath);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ec) {
      Log.d(TAG, ec.printStacktrace);
    }
}
```