# FileNotFoundExcption on connection.getInputStream(); line on API level less than 23

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, urlconnection

I am downloading HTML file from server using URLConnection but I am getting FileNotFoundException. My path is correct. Using same code same file is downloaded on android of API level 25 but on API level less than it is not downloading. Also connection.getContentLength(); is giving 311 value always. I am not getting any answer to solve this. I am hereby adding my code.

My class file code is

```
String HomeScreenResourcefilename = WebHomescreenResObj.getString("FileName");
                        int ProductTargetID = WebHomescreenResObj.getInt("ProductTargetID");

                        String WebURL_Part1 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.FileDownloadRootPath)+"/ExhibitorData/";
                        String WebURL_Part2 = GlobalVariables.tradeShowName+" - "+GlobalVariables.exhibitorName+"/HTMLHomeScreen/"+ProductTargetID +"/"+HomeScreenResourcefilename;

                        String WebURL = WebURL_Part1  + WebURL_Part2;

try {


                            URL url = new URL(WebURL);
                            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), HomeScreenResourcefilename);

                            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                            connection.connect();
                            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);


                            //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
                            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int bufferLength = 0;

                            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                            }

                            fileOutput.close();
} catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            LogE("error in 14 :"+e1);
                        }
```

Comment: Can you try changing File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), HomeScreenResourcefilename); to File file = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), HomeScreenResourcefilename);

Comment: Please tell at what line the exception throws.

Comment: InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream(); is throwing Exception.  Also using same code another file from same server with different location is downloaded successfully.

Comment: getAbsolutePath() is also not working. Same exception is there. Also tell me about that 311 content size. Whysame size always which throws exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HttpURLConnection and then connection.getResponseCode() to get the status code. If it is greater than 400, that might be the reason.
Update: Use url encoding.

Comment: I am using URLConnection so connection.getResponseCode() can not be used. Is there any another method to check response code??

Comment: URLConnection doesn't have such method. Use HttpURLConnection instead.

Comment: On API 21 I am getting 400 as response code but on API level 24 I am getting 200. How to solve the problem as file exists there?

Comment: My response is like     400:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD><BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2><hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p></BODY></HTML>

Comment: Try encoding the url. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

Comment: I have try this also but its giving 404 error on both API as space in URL is replaced by "-"

Comment: I have try part of URL to be encode but its working only on API 25 not on API below it.

Comment: Space should be encoded with + or %20. Can you show me the url?

Comment: Yes I have try this and its working. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Will you please upvote and accept the answer?

Comment: I have replaced space by %20 and half URL is encoded. Also I use HTTPURLConnection.