# passing poster path from one activity to another

Tags: java, android

I have movies app and I tried to pass name and poster of each movie from MainActivity to DetailActivity after click on movie poster, and the name passed correctly with no problems but I have problem with poster

this is the code in **MainActivity:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            Uri moviePoster = mMoviesItems.get(adapterPosition).getFullPosterPath();
            String movieName = mMoviesItems.get(adapterPosition).getName();
            mClickHandler.onClick(moviePoster, movieName);
        }
```

and this is the code for **DetailActivity:**

```
private String moviePoster;
    private String movieName;

    private ImageView mMoviePoster;
    private TextView mMovieName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        mMovieName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_movie_name);
        mMoviePoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_poster);

        Intent intentThatStartedThisActivity = getIntent();

        if (intentThatStartedThisActivity != null) {
            if (intentThatStartedThisActivity.hasExtra("moviePoster")) {
                moviePoster = intentThatStartedThisActivity.getStringExtra("moviePoster");
                mMoviePoster.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(moviePoster));
            }
            if (intentThatStartedThisActivity.hasExtra("movieName")) {
                movieName = intentThatStartedThisActivity.getStringExtra("movieName");
                mMovieName.setText(movieName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the custom class where I build the method of posters:

```
public class MovieItem extends ArrayList<MovieItem> {
    private String photo;
    private String name;

    public MovieItem(String poster_path, String original_title) {
        this.photo = poster_path;
        this.name = original_title;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Uri getFullPosterPath() {
        return Uri.parse("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendPath("w185")
                .appendEncodedPath(getPhoto())
                .build();
    }
}
```

it's correct that I define it like Uri ?
and why I get error with `getDrawable(moviePoster));` tells that

> getDrawable (int) in Resources cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: no one can help! ^^"

Comment: Try this Crease Interface pass the uri @muklah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
String uri = Uri.parse("http://...")
                    .buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
                    .build().toString();
```

> For more [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)

Comment: @muklah ok good,,,,if my answer is use full please upvote man.