# How to use URL for URL encoding?

Tags: android, android-volley, url-encoding, getmethod

I am using URL in one format. but when I enter it in Google and when pressed enter it is converting to another format.

below is my original URL

```
'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=hai basha.how are  you&target=te&key={YOUR_API_KEY}'
```

below is my encoded url

```
'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=hai%20basha.how%20are%20you&target=te&key={YOUR_API_KEY}'
```

how can I implement this in my code. Actually it is a `GET` method.

Comment: just search for `android url encode`. You will need 7 seconds to find an answer

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i didnot worked it on this before. how can I know. I thought there may be a more formats for URL Encoding.

Comment: `how can I know` that's what I wrote - **by using search before asking.**

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko it is not a good idea to be giving nagative

Comment: Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3286067/5576205) and its answers: Regards

Comment: not as bad as  not following SO rules. You know that you have to use search before asking, right?

Answer (score -1):

you can use String.replace method to change characters to their respective special character notation. and make a call through get or post or what ever you want.

Comment: this is probably the worst possible way to do it.

Comment: May be. But that I is how I used to do. If you have any better idea. Go on teach us.

Comment: Sure I know better idea, but there are already tones of answers for this question on StqckOverflow. Why should I add another one, which will be a duplicate?

Comment: You can give a link where we can probably learn.

Comment: check the question, which this question is marked a duplicate for.