# get param containing & ampersand in php post request

Tags: php, url, post, urlencode, urldecode

I want to pass param value as 'abc & pqr'. How to get it in php post request..
I tried..

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["session1"]) && isset($_REQUEST["token"]) && isset($_REQUEST["company"]) ){

    $session1   = $_REQUEST["session1"];
    $token      = $_REQUEST["token"];
    $company    = $_REQUEST["company"]; 

    $result = $session1 ." ". $token ." ". $company;
    echo $result;   
}
```

I passed param in URL as ?session1=123&token=2&company=Abc & lmn

with Output as : '123 2 Abc '
it displays only Abc .
How to get whole company value as 'Abc & lmn'?

Comment: Just add the ampersand in the string concatenation? `$result = $session1 ." & ". $token ." & ". $company;`

Comment: Your just need to urlencode the company name `Abc+%26+Imn`

Comment: Right - misunderstood the Q - before page submission, use `urlencode($value)` and the ampersand will come through as `&amp;`

Comment: @FMK how to do that ?? I am passing params from from Android Post request. Can i use Unicode char for & and then pass it to param?? but how to get it back in php?

Comment: If the android application would use a POST request you would not have this problem. The android app is using a GET request. For this the app needs to urlencode the data (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android ) in order for you to use it correctly in php!