# How to encode special characters while building url in android studio?

Tags: android, url, utf-8, urlencode

I am trying to encode a URL with special character and `OR` operator. This is how the URL looks like:

```
https://example.net/house/info?_queryFilter=_id+eq+%27333a22e7-5g5g-4sd5-df67-fg66a9da8027%27+or+_id+eq+%2756nm67d0-7687-4d70-fg45-22d6745423a7%27
```

NOTE: `333a22e7-5g5g-4sd5-df67-fg66a9da8027` and `56nm67d0-7687-4d70-fg45-22d6745423a7` in above URL indicates `houseID`

This is the code I am using for looping through the `houseID`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < apiResponse.getHouses().size(); i++) {
        if (houseQuery == null) {
            houseQuery = "_id+eq+".concat("'").concat(apiResponse.getHouses().get(i).getHouseId()).concat("'");
        } else {
            houseQuery = houseQuery.concat("+or+_id+eq+").concat("'").concat(apiResponse.getHouses().get(i).getHouseId()).concat("'");
        }
    }
```

This is my API interface:

```
@GET(UrlConstants.URL_GET_HOUSE)
void getHouseInfo(
        @Header(Constants.HEADER_SESSIONID) String sessionID,
        @Query(Constants.QUERY_FILTER) String query,
        Callback<HouseInfoResponse> houseInfoResponseCallback);
```

I am getting the following error in the logs:

`{"code":400,"reason":"Bad Request","message":"The value '_id+eq+'333a22e7-5g5g-4sd5-df67-fg66a9da8027'+or+_id+eq+'56nm67d0-7687-4d70-fg45-22d6745423a7'' for parameter '_queryFilter' could not be parsed as a valid query filter"}`

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL encoding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the sign `+` in `_id+eq+` was getting replaced with two-digit hexadecimal representation, starting with `%`), i.e. `%2B`.
The server wasn't expecting the encoding of `+` in query prefix `_id+eq+` and `+or+_id+eq+`.

**Solution:**
Specifying the `encodeValue` as `False` while specifying `Query` attribute worked.

```
@Header(Constants.HEADER_SESSIONID) String sessionID,
@Query(value = Constants.QUERY_FILTER, , encodeValue = false) String query,
    Callback<HouseInfoResponse> houseInfoResponseCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your URL to see if it works , for example use **%27** instead of **'** .

You can use this web site [to encode](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/)